# Macro for multiple matching cells detection

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am implementing a macro that checks column E for dates that are 7 days away from current date.

If cell date - current date = 7

then an email containing the row that has the matching cell is sent.
This is my coding it works successfully, except for one issue.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim rngStart As Range
Dim rngEnd As Range
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim strHtmlHead As String
Dim strHtmlFoot As String
Dim strMsgBody As String
Dim strMsgBody1 As String
Dim strMsg As String
Dim objEmail As Object
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Object

'On Error GoTo ErrHnd

'only run if between midnight and 2AM
'If Hour(Now) < 2 Then

'setup basic HTML message header and footer


'setup start of body of message
strMsgBody = "The following task(s) are due in less than 7 days :"

'Worksheet name
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'set start of date range
    Set rngStart = .Range("E1")
    'find end of date range
    Set rngEnd = .Range("E" & CStr(Application.Rows.Count)).End(xlUp)

    'loop through all used cells in column G
    For Each rngCell In .Range(rngStart, rngEnd)
        'test if date is equal to 7 days from today
        If IsDate(rngCell.Value) Then
        If rngCell.Value - Int(Now) = 7 Then
            'add to message - use task name from column A (offset -3)
            'change as required
            strMsgBody1 = strMsgBody & "<Br>" & "<Br>" & "Task: " & rngCell.Offset(0, -3).Text _
                & " is due on  " & rngCell.Text & "<Br> " & "<Br> " & "Therefore please take necessary action"
        End If
        End If
    Next rngCell

    'Note last test time/date
    rngEnd.Offset(1, -3) = Now
    rngEnd.Offset(1, -3).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
End With

'put message together
strMsg = strMsgBody1

'test message
'MsgBox strMsg

'create the e-mail object


Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutlookMail

.To = "adrianadriananthony@outlook.com"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Task Alert"
.HTMLBody = strMsg
.Send
End With


Set OutlookMail = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


'remove the e-mail object

Exit Sub

'error handler
ErrHnd:
Err.Clear

End Sub
```

When there are two or more records with the same date that matches the criterion

cell date - current date = 7

then only one record is displayed in the email and sent to the email address.

For example there are three records as shown below:

[image]

and only the third record is detected and attached to the body of the email.

**I need to know why this happens?** 
**How can I edit my code to correct this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue delete `strMsgBody1` declaration and replace every occurance with `strMsgBody`. You don't need a second variable.